# Issue with Required Field validation in a asp.net application having two pages workflow

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net application with two pages. The first page is having a next button and second page is having a back and submit button. The second page contains text box control with required field validtor.
As per current design, required field validator on 2nd page should get fired on clicking on submit button.

The issue I am having is :- User Fills the first page and then go to second page. Now, user wants to comeback to first page and then go to second page, the required field validator on text box is getting fired and showing up the error message. I dont want this. This should be like - text box should be blank and no error message should be displayed. Error messages should be displayed on clicking on the Submit button on the second page.

I tried couple of options :- 1. putting InitialValue on required field etc.. but no luck.

Could you pls help me out??

Comment: Change the `ValidationGroup` of the controls you want to validate and the validation controls, and then either leave out the `ValidationGroup` or change it on the controls you do not want to validate.

Answer (score 0):

The following Markup should solve your problem :

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbData" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Submit"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Submit" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFieldVal1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Field must be filled in."
        ControlToValidate="tbData" ValidationGroup="Submit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

These fields use the `ValidationGroup` property to set which fields will cause the validation of which validator controls.

You will notice that there is no `ValidationGroup` property on the `btnBack` button as this should not cause validation.

For more information on this see the MSDN Article for [Specifying Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: HI Nunners.. Thanks for the reply.. but couple of issue.. 1. All the buttons (both in 1st page and 2nd page) are not part of the page. these are part of Master page and i dont have control over them. 2. I am not having issue while clicking on the back button. I am having issue when user clicks the back button , go to first page and come back to 2nd page, at that time the validation message is showing up.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to show us the markup to be able to help, If you have no control over the master where these controls are, how do you intend to fix the problem?